# How to calculate weighted mean coordinates within polygons?

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, census, mac, ftools

I'm using QGIS 1.8 on OSX 10.8.3.

I have a polygon shapefile of all of the US state legislative districts.

I also have a layer of points that are centroids of US Census Tracts, with a field for the population of the tract.

How do I generate a layer of points that are the weighted mean of each census tract point within each legislative district?

My hunch is to play with spatial joins and use fTools to do mean coordinates, but I'm not sure how to calculate the mean for each polygon instead of the whole layer itself.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You want the weighted mean of your centroids per district (geographically) or simply the mean of the population weighted by the number of tracts within a district?

Comment: I believe the former. Each district contains many tract centroids, so I'd like the geographic mean center of population for each legislative district.

Comment: How about use the Vector > Analysis Tools > Mean Coordinates?

Comment: Looking to answer a similar problem- I have output area population weighted centroids for the UK and I want generate higher level (local authority level) population weighted centroids from this data- doesn't seem to do the trick if I just find the mean coordinates-any help would be really appreciated- new to GIS!

Comment: Hi Kate, welcome to SE. Instead of posting this as an answer, please create your own question thread and link back to this page.

Comment: I was looking population centroid. Based on the suburbs with their population.
How about use the Vector > Analysis Tools > Mean Coordinates?
This answer really helped.
Thanks